# Smart attribute update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have to parse an XML file each week (who got like 16k entries with 20 attributes in each entry). Parsing is not the problem but I would like to find a way to update "smartly" my attributes in my db. Knowing that in the XML file, I do not have a "last update at" field.

Is there a way to update only the attributes in db who's been updated from my XML? And not to do dirty update, no matter what.

I'm here to read your advice on how you would do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could count a hash for content of each record.
Keep this hash as one of fields in database.

Then, when you parsed XML, count hash for each of its entries, and compare it with DB hash.

If they are different - update the row in DB.

Comment: Assuming there is a modern db behind, this is absolutely meaningless. Engine won’t update fields with the same values. Just try kinda `UPDATE test SET name='...' WHERE id=...`. If the respective `name` was not changed for the given `id`, you’ll receive “0 rows updated” back.

Comment: As I understood, OP wants not to trigger update at all, if this record is present.
But it makes sense to clarify what OP wants to accomplish